# How to provide required go modules in code at the time of code commit and building application through drone.io?

Tags: go, github, go-modules

I developed one go service and deployed it on GAE. At the time of developing this application, I included required go modules using command in my work machine-

```
go get -u <module-name>
```

I am able to include other required go modules using following commands -

```
adtech-adlib-web> go mod init
```

It created one go.mod file with message-

```
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/nytm/adtech-adlib-web
```

than, I executed below command to download required modules in vendor folder as-

```
adtech-adlib-web> go mod vendor
```

Now, I want to commit this go code in my feature branch where code automatically deploys through .drone.io tool in repository. However, my build gets failed with only error :

```
cannot find package "backend" in any of:
/drone/src/github.com/nytm/adtech-adlib-web/vendor/backend (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/backend (from $GOROOT)
/drone/src/backend (from $GOPATH)
```

In my .drone.yml file section which creates problem is -

```
  backend-test:
image: jprobinson/golang-gcloud-sdk:1.11
environment:
  - GOPATH=/drone
  - PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go_appengine
commands:
  - go test -v ./backend/...
when:
  event: [push, pull_request]
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem? If go mod vendor can help in this case, how to use it and at which folder level I would have to execute this? Please explain all steps to perform.

Comment: Have you read and understood https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg hey Marks, I read article of link provided by you & now only thing breaking the build is root folder of my golang code which is in parallel with UI code, .drone.yml file and other things. This folder is not recognised by this service. I guess this particular thing will not be fixed by go mod init and vendor as this is my own folder.

Comment: running `go build` inside any valid package path should build your application regardless of what else is in there.

Answer (score 0):

From this error message, it looks like you're building in GOPATH mode (with modules disabled).

```
cannot find package "backend" in any of:
/drone/src/github.com/nytm/adtech-adlib-web/vendor/backend (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/backend (from $GOROOT)
/drone/src/backend (from $GOPATH)  <--- building in GOPATH mode
```

Try setting `GO111MODULE=on` in your environment. Since you're using a vendor directory, you may also want to set `-mod=vendor` to ensure that packages are loaded from the vendor directory instead of the module cache (and the network).

When `GO111MODULE` is not set or set to `auto`, module-aware mode is only enabled when you start the build outside `GOPATH`. This will change in go1.13: modules will also be enabled if there's a go.mod file in any parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention full github path of my golang service folder in main.go as-

import (
....

backend "github.com/org_name/repo_name/backend"

.........
)